# Why measured time inside method is way bigger than inside method?

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, measure, suspend

Imagine the following:

```kotlin
// added so that it is obvious that this it's not just a delay
inline fun <T> measure(fn: () -> T): T {
    val a = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val r = runCatching { fn() }
    val b = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val seconds = (b - a).toDouble() / 1000.0
    println("Took $seconds to complete")
    return r.getOrThrow()
}


suspend fun doSomething() = ...
suspend fun measureSomething() = measuring{
  doSomething()
} // logs 7 seconds

measuring{
  measureSomething()
} // logs 15 seconds? WHY????
```

Why the big difference?

I think one of the possible reasons could be that the CoroutineScope is waiting for children scopes to finish...

If that's the case, how can I debug that?

YET, I don't think that's the case. So another reason could be the event loop having little resources, and not releasing the thread until later on when it can... but 8 seconds doing that?

Makes no sense!

Comment: A key detail you didn't provide is how `measuring` is defined. It could delay for 7 seconds for all we know.

Comment: Sure, let's just assume it accurately logs the time it took the closure to execute. It is an inline function so that it works in suspend and non-suspend methods

Comment: "I think one of the possible reasons could be that the CoroutineScope is waiting for children scopes to finish." We would have to see what you're doing with various different scopes to comment on this possibility. Your question doesn't have enough detail that anyone could reproduce your results.